# How to predict using the Generalized Linear Modelling In R with given data point

Tags: r, glm

I am trying to predict for the year 2018 where a dataset is trained using the Poisson GLM

I have the below    data

```
        Year        Gender    Total_Apprentices
    1   2012        Female            278290
    2   2012          Male            230330
    3   2013        Female            231645
    4   2013          Male            205521
    5   2014        Female            264554
    6   2014          Male            233830
    7   2015        Female            268593
    8   2015          Male            239739
    9   2016        Female            264350
    10  2016          Male            230532
    11  2017        Female            184237
    12  2017          Male            191524
```

This is the code I have written

```
    library("xlsx")
    library("tidyverse")

    setwd("folder location") 
    getwd()
    # Loading

    # xlsx files using xlsx library

    f_path <- "filename.xlsx"

    my_data <- read.xlsx(f_path, 1, header=TRUE)
    plot(my_data)

    model1 <- glm(my_data$Total ~ my_data$Year+my_data$Gender,my_data, family= poisson)


    summary(model1)

    pois.pred <- predict(model1, type="response")

    my_data
    pois.pred
```

How would I go about predicting for the year 2018

I have tried the below code but doesn't work

```
    n_data=data.frame(Year=2018,Gender="Male")
    predict(model1, newdata=n_data, type="response")
```

I get the exact same output as this code

```
 pois.pred <- predict(model1, type="response")
```

which is basically predicting my observed value from the year 2012 to 2017 and there is a message

Warning message:
'newdata' had 1 row but variables found have 12 rows

Comment: what do you mean by it doesn't work, are you getting an error?

Comment: @DS_UNI I have updated my question explaining the error, let me know if you require more info

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the `glm` call and not the `predict` call, If you pass the data in the formula, then you will not be able to give the model new data to predict, because the variables will be called my_data$Year etc. in
the model object, not Year and Gender.

If you change the call to :

```
glm(Total_Apprentices ~ Year+Gender, 
    data = my_data, family= poisson)
```

Then the prediction on new data will work

Comment: The answer now has an explanation thanks to [atiretoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1480928/atiretoo)